# Sublime Test 4; Cancel "Goto Definition" (F12)

Tags: sublimetext3

I noticed that the behavior in Sublime Text 4 seems to have changed in the latest release. Previously I could hit F12 to bring up all the definitions of a symbol with a little pop-up showing a list of all instances. I could preview them all using the arrow keys to navigate and then hit ESC to return from where I came.
It seems that since the latest version, hitting escape lands me on whichever page I was previewing. Previously this would require me pressing "enter".
Does anyone know if this is now a setting or how I can get the old functionality back?

Comment: Your question says `"changed in the latest release"` and tags Sublime Text 3, but the last release of ST3 was in 2019. So just to clarify, were you using a really old version of ST3 that just recently updated, or are you actually using Sublime Text 4? (You can tell by checking the build number displayed in `Help > About` ; if it's in the 4000's, it's ST4.

Comment: Ah, good catch. I'm on Build 4121. I didn't realize that it had updated me to ST4 at some point. My start menu entry still says "Sublime Text 3"

Comment: This is driving me crazy, any solutions? I can't find a diff for the default keymap, if that is to blame... @OdatNurd

Comment: Ok I found an old build's keymap, the only difference is the addition of `{ "key": "panel_has_focus", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }` in `hide_overlay`. Removing this doesn't seem to change anything. I found a workaround: if you click on another file while in the GOTO popup, then hit ESC, you will pop back to the original file.

Comment: @Otus you may want to double check in Safe Mode; I can't replicate this personaly, it works as it always has. As a quick check, if you use `Preferences > Browse Packages` and see a folder named `Default`, that is a potential cause for issues like this. In such a case you could try temporarily moving it away (e.g. to your Desktop) and restarting Sublime to see if the situation improves.

Comment: Btw I am running OSX, maybe it is an OSX issue.

Comment: I'm running windows. I just tried in safe mode and the behavior is the same. No "default" folder in packages either.

Comment: Also, I can confirm that the workaround @koe proposes also restores the desired behavior for me. However, that's pretty tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding one workaround based on koe's suggestion. It seems like if you switch tabs before hitting escape, Sublime exhibits the desired behavior. With this in mind I tried to bind a keystroke to switch tabs and the issue the "cancel" command and it worked.

I bound this command chain to the "escape" key and it has restored my workflow. I'm not sure if this will have implications for using escape in another context but I'll update if I find out anything else.

```
{ "keys": ["escape"],
    "command": "chain",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
          ["next_view_in_stack"],
          ["cancel"],
        ]
    }
},
```

*EDIT: Above version doesn't handle ctrl+p followed by esc. Also doesn't allow find panel to be close by escape. Was able to modify it to be more targeted.*

```
{ "keys": ["escape"],
    "command": "chain",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
          ["next_view_in_stack"],
          ["prev_view_in_stack"],
          ["cancel"],
        ]
    },
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "overlay_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "panel_has_focus", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the edited solution as well :p it fixed some issues I found.

Comment: Glad to help! I wouldn't have found it without your workaround :)